# Get variable from a function into a list

Tags: python, json, twitter, rss

I tried to make this question not localized, but since my knowledge of Python is very primitive, please feel free to edit it to make it clearer!

Twitter is on its last stages on dropping support for XML, including RSS, and I'm fighting to get the same behaviour by parsing the json provided by Twitter and getting the output with PyRSS2Gen. I took this link as an example: https://github.com/dschep/Twitter-user_timeline.rss-proxy/blob/master/timeline_rss_proxy.py

I actually got it working, but retweets are most of the times truncated. But it is possible to get the whole tweet with `item['retweeted_status']['text']` instead of `item['text']`. I need to get a regex part of `item['text']` (^RT @username:) and join it with `item['retweeted_status']['text']`.

So I created a function called "get_tweet_text", and I want to fill the values of **title** and **description** on the `items` list with the output from this function, but the function seems to be just ignored, so I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 59, in <module>
    ) for item in feed
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyRSS2Gen.py", line 397, in __init__
    "must define at least one of 'title' or 'description'")
TypeError: must define at least one of 'title' or 'description'
```

Here is the full code. I obscured my application and user keys with X. `sys.argv[1]` refers to the user whose timeline is to be downloaded. Please, feel free to correct more mistakes you may find :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, re, datetime, urlparse, json, PyRSS2Gen
import oauth2 as oauth

name = sys.argv[1]

consumer = oauth.Consumer(
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)
token = oauth.Token(
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(
    'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=%s'
    % name,
    method='GET',
)
feed = json.loads(content)

link_tmpl = 'http://twitter.com/{user}/status/{id}'

def get_tweet_text(item):
#   try:
    text = '%s: %s %s' % (
        name,
        re.search('^RT @\w+:', item['text']).group(0),
        item['retweeted_status']['text']
    )
#   except:
#       text = item['text']

rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
    title = 'Twitter / {0}'.format(name),
    link = 'http://twitter.com/{0}'.format(
        feed[0]['user']['name'].encode('utf-8')
    ),
    description = feed[0]['user']['description'],

    lastBuildDate = datetime.datetime.now(),

    items = [
        PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
            title       = get_tweet_text(item),
            link        = link_tmpl.format(user=name, id=item['id']),
            description = get_tweet_text(item),
            guid        = PyRSS2Gen.Guid(link_tmpl.format(
                user=name, id=item['id']
            )),
            pubDate     = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                item['created_at'][:19] + item['created_at'][25:],
                '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
            )
        ) for item in feed
    ]
)

print rss.to_xml()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything from your `get_tweet_text` function. You just need `return text` at the end.

Comment: Hahaha, it will take me some time to get used to the idea that Python is not Bash! Thanks!